# launch exe from inf installation

Tags: installation, driver, inf

in my recent project, i have to launch an exe from inf.
when my company's device is plugged into win 7 system, PnP service will search device driver from Windows Update Server and install it automatically.
on the last step, i must start a app.
how can i do that from inf installaton? Please help!!!
i tried writing a stub ocx and call shellexecute in dllregisterserver. when i register it manually using regsvr32 command, i works, but it doesn't work on automatic installation(shellexecute succeeds but nothing happens). it seems that system forbiddens it.
Could anybody give me some advice?Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is forbidden (or at least deprecated) to call executables from an inf installation file.

WHQL tests will fail, if you have such a line in your inf file.

What you can do, is have a process already running, which registers itself to wait on a device interface to appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want register a DLL inside of INF-based installation you can use `RegisterDlls` directive in the `DefaultInstall` section (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547356.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547460.aspx).